# Lowe Alpine - TFX Cerro Torre: pack is moving to sides

Tags: gear, backpacking

I bought a new pack Love Alpine TFX Cerro Torre 65:85 ([this one](http://www.lowealpine.com/tfx-cerro-torre-65-85)). I am quite satisfied, but have one problem.

The pack is moving to sides and isn't very stable. On begs it fits really well, bat the body of the pack is moving. Maybe I just have to set straps properly. But I have no idea how.

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Do you know how to adjust all 6 straps on a modern backpack? That also might make for a better question in this format: one that would be more generally useful to a lot of people. Just an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess based off the photo you have linked is that the top tensioners(top stabilizers) are not adjusted properly, this or perhaps the hipbelt needs some adjustment.  Try the following:

  Put the pack on, place the hipbelt directly over your hip bones, fasten the buckle, and tighten the hipbelt. The padding should wrap right around your hip bones.

  Snug in the shoulder straps. They should be far enough apart that they don't squeeze your neck. The strap ends should be no more than 10cm (4in.) from your armpits.

  Adjust the top stabilizer straps to a comfortable position. They should be at about a 45-degree angle.

  Fasten the sternum strap and adjust the lower stabilizing straps until comfortable.